# Laravel: You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

My laravel project is throwing error on sub-domain of hosting. My code is working fine on other hosting's sub-domain. However, on this here is shows error as show in image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ9bX.png).

**My .htaccess file**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me out to solve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks like your subdomain is not pointing to the correct dir, or the permissions on the server are not correct. Make sure the subdomain is pointing to the applications public folder

Comment: @GertB. Thank you for time. Subdomain is pointing to correct dir but I don't know how to resolve the permission issue.